# Combine XML files similar to ConfigParser's multiple file support

Tags: python, xml, configuration-files

I'm writing an application configuration module that uses XML in its files. Consider the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <PathA>/Some/path/to/directory</PathA>
    <PathB>/Another/path</PathB>
</Settings>
```

Now, I'd like to override certain elements in a different file that gets loaded afterwards. Example of the override file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <PathB>/Change/this/path</PathB>
</Settings>
```

When querying the document (with overrides) with XPath, I'd like to get this as the element tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <PathA>/Some/path/to/directory</PathA>
    <PathB>/Change/this/path</PathB>
</Settings>
```

This is similar to what Python's ConfigParser does with its [read()](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read) method, but done with XML. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the XML into an instance of Python class:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import io

class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self,text):
        root=ET.parse(io.BytesIO(text)).getroot()
        self.settings=dict((elt.tag,elt.text) for elt in root.xpath('/Settings/*'))
    def update(self,other):
        self.settings.update(other.settings)

text='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <PathA>/Some/path/to/directory</PathA>
    <PathB>/Another/path</PathB>
</Settings>'''

text2='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <PathB>/Change/this/path</PathB>
</Settings>'''    

s=Settings(text)
s2=Settings(text2)
s.update(s2)
print(s.settings)
```

yields

```
{'PathB': '/Change/this/path', 'PathA': '/Some/path/to/directory'}
```

Comment: In the end I did go with JSON, but I implemented this as well when researching on the subject. Creating your own classes to represent the configuration is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Must you use XML? The same could be achieved with [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) much simpler:
Suppose this is the text from the first config file:

```
text='''
{
  "PathB": "/Another/path", 
  "PathA": "/Some/path/to/directory"
}
'''
```

and this is the text from the second:

```
text2='''{
  "PathB": "/Change/this/path"
}'''
```

Then to merge the to, you simply load each into a `dict`, and call `update`:

```
import json
config=json.loads(text)
config2=json.loads(text2)
config.update(config2)
print(config)
```

yields the Python `dict`:

```
{u'PathB': u'/Change/this/path', u'PathA': u'/Some/path/to/directory'}
```

Comment: JSON is not out of the question, but I thought XML would be handy with XPaths and all that.